# Irreducible polynomials in Z[X]

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratics, irreducible-polynomials

could you please confirm my method of solution for the following question? Thanks in advance!! :)

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 - 2x + 1 \in \mathbb Z[X]$. Prove that $f $ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$.

Solution: I tried to use Einstein's Criterion but it clearly does not work here. So I tried to solve for $x$ by using the Tschirnaus Transformation and turn it into a compress cubic and solve for $x$. I got $x_1, x_2, x_3 = $ some number that consists of nested square roots and the complex number i.

In this case, isn't it sufficient to show that $f$ is irreducible since the solution $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are clearly not in the set of Rationals?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Excluding integer / rational roots is a bit easier than finding all the roots. Have you heard about the rational root theorem?

Comment: A degree $3$ polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is reducible if and only if it has a root in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Arthur Not really. I am looking it up right now. :(

Comment: @Arthur Do you think my way is still correct? Because this is from the final exam, and the prof marked it as incorrect and awarded me a 0 out of 5. I am planning to petition it.

Comment: @Wilson `the solution x_1, x_2, x_3 are clearly not in the set of Rationals` It's not enough to say `clearly`, you need to *prove* that. Just because an expression contains radicals, it doesn't mean it can't be rational, and just because it contains $i$ it doesn't mean it can't be real.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for your reply. In your opinion, do you think my approach will eventually lead me to completing the proof (in other words, what I wrote should be awarded 1 to 2 marks for showing it)? Or is my approach just completely off?

Comment: @Wilson Realistically, I don't see that working. If you *did* work it out somehow, then it would (have to) be equivalent to proving the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) itself. But if you knew or proved that, then you wouldn't have had to actually solve the cubic to begin with. I think the perseverence to try, and the effort to solve a non-trivial cubic could be worth a point by themselves, but then I am not the one doing the grading, and the cold fact is that you missed what was supposed to be the easy way out this time around.

Comment: @dxiv I see. Thanks! I'll try to petition it. It doesn't hurt. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frac{p}{q}$ is a rational solution of $x^3+x^2-2x+1$ with $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p,q$ coprime then

$$\frac{p^3}{q^3}+\frac{p^2}{q^2}-2\frac{p}{q}+1=0 \Leftrightarrow p^3+p^2q-2pq^2+q^3 = 0\Leftrightarrow p(p^2+pq-2q^2) = -q^3.$$ This implies that $p|q$. But since $p$ and $q$ are coprime it follows $p=\pm 1$. In the same way

$$\frac{p^3}{q^3}+\frac{p^2}{q^2}-2\frac{p}{q}+1=0 \Leftrightarrow p^3+p^2q-2pq^2+q^3 = 0\Leftrightarrow -p^3 = q(p^2-2pq+q^2).$$ This implies $q|p$. But since since $p$ and $q$ are coprime it follows $q=\pm 1$.

Hence, if there is a rational root of  $x^3+x^2-2x+1$ it must be $\pm 1$ which is obviously not a solution. Consequently there is no rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $(x-\frac{p}{q})\mid ( x^3+x^2-2x+1)$ which proves that $x^3+x^2-2x+1$ is irreducible.